# How to use original parameter in `_.wrap` function in Underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

For example, I have a `example` function, it has two parameters `a` and `b`.

```
var example = function(a, b){...}
```

Now I want to wrap this function, do some changes to parameter `b`, how can I get `a` in my wrap function?

```
example = _.wrap(example, function(original)){
    //do some changes to b
    ....
    original(?, b)//how can i get a
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will get the original parameter as arguments to the wrapper function in the same order as it was passed after the original function argument.

In the below example `a` and `b` will be the 2 parameters passed to the `hello` function.

```js
var hello = function(p1, p2) {
  return p1 + ": " + p2;
};
hello = _.wrap(hello, function(func, a, b) {
  return "before, " + func(a, b + 'Name') + ", after";
});
snippet.log(hello('hellow', 'User'));
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore-min.js"></script>
```